# Time of the day dimension

Tags: data-warehouse

How can I build a time-of-the-day dimension table which holds granular information for hours, minutes, seconds and such information

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdata-warehouse%5D+%22time+dimension%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got it from here - http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Date_and_Time_dimensions

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious why you would want a TIME dimension when this information can easily be extracted from the TIME portion of a TIMESTAMP or TIME data type itself. Having said that you could create a table `DIM_TIME (Time, Hour, Minute, Seconds)`. You would then have to populate it with 86400 values containing a record for each second within a 24 hour period.